# PHP handling multipart/form-data

Tags: php, html

Sorry for the title, because I don't know how to name this problem. Please consider the following code

```
<?php
var_dump($_POST);
?>
<form name="submit_form" id="submit_form" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="hidden" name="update" value="y">
    <input type="file" name="supplement_file" id="supplement_file" class="btn_general" />
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

It's a PHP that simply do printing the submitting information. The first run, it displays empty, that makes sense. However, after I click submit, it still shows empty. But the request payload has been set already. I can see it via network tab in console.

```
------WebKitFormBoundaryO78Y428dBFHmIDbk
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="update"

y
------WebKitFormBoundaryO78Y428dBFHmIDbk
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="supplement_file"; filename="supplement2.wmv"
Content-Type: video/x-ms-wmv


------WebKitFormBoundaryO78Y428dBFHmIDbk--
```

What I expect is I can see the `"update"="y"` after I submit this form.

I am using PHP 5.3 is that is the problem? And the content-type is strange. It's `Content-Type:text/html` in this submit. Am I missing something?

**UPDATE**

The header information of the request

```
Connection:Keep-Alive
Content-Length:369
Content-Type:text/html
Date:Tue, 30 Dec 2014 10:01:22 GMT
Keep-Alive:timeout=5, max=100
Server:Apache/2.2.17 (Win32) mod_ssl/2.2.17 OpenSSL/0.9.8o PHP/5.3.4 mod_perl/2.0.4 Perl/v5.10.1
X-Powered-By:PHP/5.3.5
```

Comment: Try var_dump($_REQUEST);

Comment: You could also try and wrap `var_dump($_POST)` in `if($_POST) {var_dump($_POST);}` So now this will only be executed when the form is submited

Comment: What is the error.it's working perfectly for me

Comment: @madforstrength not works.

Comment: @Priyank The problem is `var_dump($_POST)` shows empty event I submit the form. No error displays. It never happens before.

Comment: @PandaYang:did you tried my code below.it's not showing empty var_dump($_POST) for me.i'm getting this output  //array (size=1)
  'update' => string 'y' (length=1)

Comment: Thanks, can you try var_dump($_REQUEST); as suggested by @madforstrength and tell us whether that shows your form input?

Comment: @Priyank Yes I tried. But it still shows empty. If I don't select the file to upload. Just clicking submit, it displays fine. Has you choose a file to upload?

Comment: which kind of file you are uploading? because i tried with images

Comment: @Koen Yes I tried. If I don't select the file to upload, It works fine. If choose a file to upload, it displays empty.

Comment: @Priyank I am uploading a .wmv file

Comment: Thanks, can you open your php.ini file (are you working locally?) and tell me youre post_max_size and upload_max_filesize?

Comment: can you share that file with me,i'll try on my server to upload that file with my code

Comment: @Koen the current setting is `upload_max_filesize = 128M` and I am uploading a 30.6MB wmv file

Comment: And what about post_max_size?

Comment: @Priyank Yes sure. But the file size is 30.6MB large. How can I give you?

Comment: @Koen Oh! I see current setting is `post_max_size = 8M`. so it's the problem.

Comment: @Priyank Yes, It works. Thanks so much. I always miss the size setting.

Answer (score 3):

Please open your php.ini file and search for these two lines:

`; Maximum size of POST data that PHP will accept.
post_max_size = 8M`

Increase the post_max_size to a higher value.

Answer (score 0):

Yes I can see the `"update"="y"`. it's working perfectly!!!

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
  <title>Untitled Document</title>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <?php
    if($_POST){
      var_dump($_POST);
    };
  ?>
  <form name="submit_form" id="submit_form" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="hidden" name="update" value="y">
    <input type="file" name="supplement_file" id="supplement_file" class="btn_general" />
    <input type="submit" />
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It doesn't works for me. I think is the server setting problem.

Comment: please provide us your server details

Answer (score 0):

Pls  add action into form.and then try.

The form is required to have an action attribute in HTML4. If it's not set, the browser will likely use the same method as providing an empty string to it. You really should set action="" which is perfectly valid HTML4, follows standards, and achieves the same exact result.

```
<?php
var_dump($_POST);
?>
<form action="" name="submit_form" id="submit_form" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
    <input type="hidden" name="update" value="y">
    <input type="file" name="supplement_file" id="supplement_file" class="btn_general" />
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```